# Limit of the double average mean of a bounded integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let's assume that $f$ is a bounded integrable function on $[0,1]$, and let us consider a sequence $t_n\downarrow 0$.

Let us assume that there exists (**thanks zhw.**) $$\bar{f}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{t_n}\int_0^{t_n}f(t)\ dt.$$ Now let us consider the double average means, in paticular the following limits:

\begin{align}
\textrm{a)}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{t_n^2}\int_0^{t_n}\int_0^tf(\tau)\ d\tau\ dt,\\
\textrm{b)}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{t_n^2}\int_0^{t_n}\tau f(\tau)\ d\tau,\\
\textrm{c)}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{t_n^2}\int_0^{t_n}f(t)\int_0^tf(\tau)\ d\tau \ dt.
\end{align}

In particular I would really like to see that both a), b) and c) equal $\bar{f}$. However I'm not quite sure how to proceed, even though I cannot come up with any counterexample.

Is it true that a), b) and c) equal $\bar{f}$? Is it a known result?
Thanks for the references or the help.

Bests, Guido

Comment: There's no reason to think the limit defining $\bar f$ exists.

Comment: @zhw. yes you're right, i edit